# 500 Joomla\CMS\Form\Form::getInstance() could not load file on Multicategories Component

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, php7

I have a site that I upgraded from Joomla 2.5 to 3.10.12. The previous site is using [Multicategories v1.0.4](http://milkdev.com/en/blog/43-multicategories-component-for-joomla25-version-104-released) component, it doesn't work on Joomla 3.10 and there is no update from the Author so I tried to upgrade the component manually.

I got it to work until the Control Panel tab: http://www.domain.local/administrator/index.php?option=com_multicategories
[image]

But when I click on Categories, I get the error below: http://www.domain.local/administrator/index.php?option=com_multicategories&view=categories&extension=com_multicategories

`500 Joomla\CMS\Form\Form::getInstance() could not load file`
[image]

File directory: `administrator/components/com _multicategories`

[image]

I tried searching for solutions online but couldn't find much and it does work on me.

Any advice on how I can fix this or what is causing the error? thanks

Comment: In your global configuration settings enable Debug and set Error Reporting to Maximum or Development and should get a more specific indication of which line of code the error is coming from.

Comment: The first link in your question to the original developers site can be removed as the domain no longer exists, it is just a broken link. Why is it important to get this abandoned project working on Joomla 3 and have you looked at alternatives to achieve whatever it is you need to achieve? I am interested in the context around this and your previous question.

Comment: Already set error_reporting to Development but that's the only error that I get on the admin panel. Multicategories component was used to filter article by categories like `https://www.gemango.com/web-development-category` or `https://www.gemango.com/entertainment` ( you can click the link in the categories ). I was advice to make the plug-in work on Joomla 3 or just remove the article-category filtering if I wasn't able to.